# How to redirect after my form submission

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I would like to know how to redirect to a confirmation/thank you page after the form is submitted, please. It's a very simple inquiry form - only collecting Name, Email, Phone number and a question. I tried using Redirect.response but it gave me an error message. I'm not sure of the correct place to put it.

Here is my script code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>
<script language="vb" runat="server">

Sub Send2Mail (sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

Dim objMail as New MailMessage()

  objMail.To = "me@myemail.com"
  objMail.From = strEmail.Text

  objMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
  objMail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal

  objMail.Body = "Name : " + strName.Text + vbNewLine + "Email : " + strEmail.text + vbnewLine + "Message : " + strQuestion.text

  SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "email.myemailserver.net"
  SmtpMail.Send(objMail)

  strQuestion.Visible = true

End Sub   
</script>
```

And the form code:

```
<form runat="server"><br />

      Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <asp:textbox id="strName" runat="server" />
      <br><br>
      Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <asp:textbox id="strEmail" runat="server" />
       <br><br>
       Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <asp:textbox id="strPhone" runat="server" />
       <br><br>

       Question:&nbsp;
      <asp:textbox id="strQuestion" runat="server" Columns="16" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" />
        <p align="center">
      <asp:button runat="server" id="func" Text="Send Message" 
                  OnClick="Send2Mail" />
                  </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: This is not a C# question. I have removed the tag.

Comment: Where did u place `response.redirect` and what kind of error message did u get?

Comment: I placed it before the closing End Sub tag like this: response.redirect(urlgoeshere.com/confirmation-page.html) and the error message I got was that I needed to make a web.config file with custom error messages set to OFF. I tried that, and then it redirected the page immediately without even displaying the page with the form.

Comment: response.redirect() takes string parameter, so it needs double quotes. Also, it allows relative file paths, so, if the target page in the same folder, as the original form page, you can just name file. So, please try if calling it like this helps: `response.redirect("confirmation-page.html")`